# Sprinkler Control Power supply requirements questions

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, solenoid, solenoid-valve

Not sure if this is the right forum or not...

I am looking to build a custom sprinkler controller using a Raspberry Pi and a relay board. The question is around the power supply. The valve (http://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/Hunter-Sprinkler-Irrigation-Valve-p/pgv-075-asv-s.htm) is listed as having these specs: 24VAC, 370mA inrush current, 190mA holding current, 60 cycles; 475mA inrush current, 230mA holding current, 50 cycles

I have a power supply that is 1000mA (http://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/Hunter-Controller-Transformer-p/52-6500.htm).

First question is I am confused why the two different specs on the valve, 50 vs 60 cycles?

Second question is if the power supply is 1000mA and I connect through a relay that means if I turn the relay on the valve will be getting close to 1000mA. Will this cause problems in the short or long term for the valve?

Let me know if there is any questions.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:  The difference is because worldwide some power distribution systems are 50Hz, and some are 60Hz.  The coil in the valve reacts differently for the different supply frequencies.

Question 2: That 1000mA rating is the maximum the power supply can deliver.  The actual valve will only use what it needs to; you won't damage it in any way by using a higher capacity (current wise) supply as long as the applied voltage is proper.